# I am trying to make an array of lists with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need an array that holds either an array of records or a list of records.  I need something like this:

```
people = [['David','Blue','Dog','Car'],['Sally','Yellow','Cat','Boat']]
```

or:

```
people = (['David','Blue','Dog','Car'],['Sally','Yellow','Cat','Boat'])
```

But I keep getting:

```
people = ['David','Blue','Dog','Car','Sally','Yellow','Cat','Boat']
```

I've tried append vs concatenate, different axis, different np initialization, but the results is always the same. Here is my latest version.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

# Tried
# people = np.empty((0,0), dtype='S')
# people = np.array([[]])
people = np.array([])

records = GetRecordsFromDB()

for record in records:

    # Do some stuff    
    
    # Tried
    # person = [name, color, animal, vehicle]
    person = np.array([name, color, animal, vehicle])

    # Tried this with different axis
    # people = np.append(people, person, axis=0)
    people = np.concatenate((people, person))
```

Thank you.

EDIT: This will be the input for a Pandas DataFrame if that helps.

Comment: What is the format/structure of record?  Also, please provide a sample of the data in record

Comment: Four strings: name, color, animal, vehicle.  I can put them in any format, but I need to be able to add those, as a list, to an array.  So I end up with an array that holds n number of records in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.c_`

```
people = np.c_[people, person]
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what I want.  Please reread what I need.

Comment: Check now @user390480

Comment: I figured it out.  The problem was the adding the first record.  Your code would only work for me in the context of my if statement.

Answer (score 0):

### edit

Looking at your answer I realized I took your subject line too literally.  [360] and following makes an array of lists.  But [356] is a 2d array, where each "row" looks like a list - but it isn't.

### earlier

```
In [354]: alist = [['David','Blue','Dog','Car'],['Sally','Yellow','Cat','Boat']]
     ...: 
In [355]: alist
Out[355]: [['David', 'Blue', 'Dog', 'Car'], ['Sally', 'Yellow', 'Cat', 'Boat']]
In [356]: np.array(alist)
Out[356]: 
array([['David', 'Blue', 'Dog', 'Car'],
       ['Sally', 'Yellow', 'Cat', 'Boat']], dtype='<U6')
```

That makes a 2d array of strings.  The construction is no different from the textbook example of making a 2d numeric array:

```
In [358]: np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Out[358]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

With `hstack` or `concatenate`:

```
In [359]: np.hstack(alist)
Out[359]: 
array(['David', 'Blue', 'Dog', 'Car', 'Sally', 'Yellow', 'Cat', 'Boat'],
      dtype='<U6')
```

To make an array with just 2 lists, you have to initial one:

```
In [360]: arr = np.empty(2, object)
In [361]: arr
Out[361]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [362]: arr[:] = alist
In [363]: arr
Out[363]: 
array([list(['David', 'Blue', 'Dog', 'Car']),
       list(['Sally', 'Yellow', 'Cat', 'Boat'])], dtype=object)
```

If the lists differ in length,

```
In [364]: np.array([["David", "Blue"], ["Sally", "Yellow", "Cat"]])
<ipython-input-364-be12d6dec312>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([["David", "Blue"], ["Sally", "Yellow", "Cat"]])
Out[364]: 
array([list(['David', 'Blue']), list(['Sally', 'Yellow', 'Cat'])],
      dtype=object)
```

Read that warning - in full.

By default `np.array` tries to make a multidimensional array of base classes like int or string.  It's only when it can't that it falls back on making an object dtype array.  That kind of arrays should be viewed as second-class array, and used only when it really is needed. Often the list of lists is just as good.

Your iterative creation is one such case

```
people = []

records = GetRecordsFromDB()

for record in records:

    # Do some stuff    
    
    # Tried
    # person = [name, color, animal, vehicle]
    person = np.array([name, color, animal, vehicle])
    people = append(person)
```

Items, whether lists or array (or anything else) can be added to a list in-place with just the addition of a reference.  Trying use `concatenate` to add items of an array is, not only harder to get right, but slower, since it is making a whole new array each time.  That means a lot of copying!

`np.append` is a badly named way of calling `concatenate`.  It is not a `list.append` clone.

Using `np.concatenate` requires a careful handling of dimensions.  Don't be sloppy, thinking it will figure out what you want.

Similarly this is not a close of list `[]`:

```
In [365]: np.array([])
Out[365]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [366]: np.array([]).shape
Out[366]: (0,)
```

It is a 1d array with a specific shape.  You can only concatenate it with another 1d array - one the only axis, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this:

```
import numpy as np

people = np.array([])

records = GetRecordsFromDB()

for record in records:

    # Do some stuff

    person = np.array([name, color, animal, vehicle])
                  
    if len(people) == 0:
        people = [person]
    else:
        people = np.append(people, [person], axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.array([person])` is a (1,4) shaped array.  You could have just as as well initialed `people=None`, and done a `if people is None:...` test.  `None` is a common "uninitialized" value.  Keep in mind though that this array append will be slower than a list append.

Comment: So you really aren't trying to make an array of lists.  You want to iteratively make a 2d array.  Details matter when programming as you found out, and they also help when asking questions.

Comment: @hpaulj, sorry, yes, I don't know the difference between an array of lists and a 2d array, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you haven't read enough basic `numpy` documentation.